# How can I filter (LogCat) the debug logging for intent resolution

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to debug the resolution of an Intent in android.

I am using the [FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION) as described in the official docs.

The question is **Which filter should I setup in the LogCat so that I can see only the logs related to the intent resolution debugging.**

I've already tried `tag:IntentResolver` and `tag:.*Intent.*` without success.

Comment: see the source vode, hth, http://androidxref.com/4.0.3_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/IntentResolver.java

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried tag:IntentResolver, but I was not able to see the logs. It turned out to be a silly problem: I forgot to call startActivity(intent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tag:IntentResolver` as filter for LogCat you can see the resolution debug info.